# htaccess allowing png files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm using the following .htaccess file trying not to allow 
access to physical php files and redirect requests to index.php.
It works nicely but brings a problem.

References to a png file or an icon file are redirected (logically :() to index.php.
I tried to add a rule in order to avoid this but I failed.

Any ideas on how not to redirect png and icon files to index.php?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes

RewriteEngine On

#Secure access to php files except from index.php
<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
#Allow access only to index files of each folder.
<FilesMatch "^(index)\.php$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>


# Index.php is the only gateway to the webapp
# If the request is for a real directory (one that exists on the server), index.php isn't served.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#If the request is for a file that exists already on the server, index.php isn't served.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rt=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I don't see any reason why it would do that, try adding `RewriteBase /` above your first `RewriteCond`

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess? Is this in DocumentRoot or in a sub directory.

Comment: Couldn't you just add another `FilesMatch` with the regex: `\.(png|ico)$` and `Allow from all`?

Comment: I have tried RewriteBase / with no result.
.htaccess is located in localhost/applicationdir/.
@SuperScript still png icons are rerouted in index.php